# How can I select all sheets in a workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

The workbook has over 50 worksheets and I'm working through an old macro that will help me amend the same range within each sheet. However they have hardcoded the `sheets.select` statement.

How do you write: `Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Bob", "1953", etc, etc, etc)).Select` so that all the sheets are selected - from first to last, no matter what name someone has given them?

Comment: In general, Excel questions belong to Super User. However, questions about VBA, even if in Excel, are better suited for a programming site. Migrating your question to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Select`

Comment: It's that easy? Why on earth did someone write it hard coded before. Sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a hard time with this.   This is for selecting a range of sheets and excluding certain ones by name.  Master, Data, and Blank1 were sheets I want to exclude from my selection.  Replace:=False is what keeps the previously selected sheet "selected" and then adds the new sheet to the current selection

```
  For i = 1 To Sheets.Count

    If Sheets(i).Name <> "Master" And Sheets(i).Name <> "Data" And Sheets(i).Name <> "blank1" Then
        
        Sheets(i).Select Replace:=False

    End If

  Next i
```